# How to close parent form and open child?

Tags: vb.net

Hey guys before I was just hiding the parent form, but now when I try to read from the parent file it says it can't because it's already running in a process. I followed some tutorial and it said to go to the project properties and have the application stop running when all the forms are closed.

But now since I did that it says the directory can't be found probably because I am reading the input from the parent form. Anyways here is my code

```
Dim writeFile1 As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite("C:\Users\Nick\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\LoginFixed\Accounts\" + frmLogin.txtUser.Text))
```

How should I go about doing this?

Edit:

```
    Private Sub btnHunter_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnHunter.Click
    selection = "Hunter"
    writeData.classSelection()
End Sub
```

This is what I have when the button is clicked.

Here is the classSelection sub:

```
    Public Sub classSelection()
    If frmClass.selection = "Hunter" Then
        writeFile1.WriteLine(frmClass.selection)
    End If
    If frmClass.selection = "Gatherer" Then
        writeFile1.WriteLine(frmClass.selection)
    End If
    If frmClass.selection = "Farmer" Then
        writeFile1.WriteLine(frmClass.selection)
    End If
    writeFile1.Close()
End Sub
```

The error points to this line:

```
If frmClass.selection = "Hunter" Then
```

Saying part of the file path cannot be found.

Comment: which one is the parent form ? .. frmLogin or .. ?

Comment: frmLogin is the parent form. @matzone

Comment: What's the real problem ?  .. **closing parent form** or **reading input form parent** ?

Comment: I'm wanting to close the parent form and read the input from the text box from the parent form. @matzone

Comment: Once you're done writing to your file with `writeFile1` are you calling `writeFile1.Close()`?

Comment: U will have 2 files for reading, both will have same data. one will be used in Parent form and 2nd in Child form, and u will have to update both files, if any change occurs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read input textbox in closed parent form, you have to declare public var

Make a new module in your project .. and add this

```
public sLogin as String
```

And before you hide or close frmLogin .. add this

```
sLogin =  txtUser.Text
```

So, you could change your code with

```
Dim writeFile1 As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite("C:\Users\Nick\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\LoginFixed\Accounts\" & sLogin))
```

Comment: Still saying it can't find part of the path.

Comment: I'm declaring it in my WriteUserDataClass

Comment: **can't find part of the path** .. where you get the path ?

Comment: What's the exact wording of the exception? What you say it is, doesn't seem to be one of the documented exceptions for OpenWrite

Answer (score 0):

matzone has given you a good hint. And to check exactly what your path is, just add a MessageBox using variables :

```
Dim writePath1 As String
Dim writeFile1 As StreamWriter

writePath1 = "C:\Users\Nick\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\LoginFixed\Accounts\" & sLogin
If MessageBox.Show(writePath1, "Continue ?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then
    writeFile1 = New StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(writePath1))
    ' ...
    writeFile1.Close() ' Very important ! Adrian pointed it out.
End If
```

^^ and if it works, you can discard the Dialog test or replace it by some test code like If File.Exists(...)

However, I don't understand wether you want to ***close*** the parent Form or ***hide*** it. It's different !
Closing the parent Form will discard any access to parent Form members, including **txtUser.Text**.

If you want to close the parent Form, the ChildForm should not be a child of that parent you are trying to close, or you must just hide the parent Form :

```
frmLogin.Hide() ' Not frmLogin.Close()
```

If you close frmLogin, frmLogin.txtUser won't be accessible, or use sLogin provided by matzone instead. Alternatively, you should pass frmLogin.txtUser.Text value to a custom property of ChildForm.

```
Imports System.IO
Public Partial Class ChildForm1
    ' Inherits System.Windows.Form
    ' ...
    Private _txtUserFile As String

    Public WriteOnly Property TxtUserFile() As String
        Set(ByVal NewFileName As String)
            _txtUserFile = NewFileName
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub LoadFile()
        Dim writeFile1 As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite("C:\Users\Nick\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\LoginFixed\Accounts\" & txtUserFile))
        ' ...
        writeFile1.Close()
    End sub
    ' ...
End Class
```

Then use this in parent Form :

```
MyChildForm.TxtUserFile = Me.txtUser.Text
' Me.Close() ' This will definately KILL Form1 (the parent one)
Me.Hide() ' Always use Hide() until you'll terminate your Application
MyChildForm.Show()
MyChildForm.LoadFile()
```

^^ but this is not a good code either ! Your problem remains unclear (at least for me)
"*Still saying it can't find part of the path*", then check the path..

- Does the file actually exists ?
- Does the path contains glitch ? (use the provided MessageBox test)
- Does your account can access that directory ? (Windows configuration and account levels)

Answer (score 0):

Well !

In fact, the problem could be somewhere else.

For example, I was able to reproduce your exception by providing an empty string [""] as the value of, either :

```
frmLogin.txtUser.Text ' = ""
' or 
sLogin ' = ""
' or
txtUserFile ' = ""
```

In fact, I get the "*Could not find a part of the path...*" exception because the StreamWriter couldn'd read/write to a File, as I didn't provided a valid FileName for that file. As the filename parameter was an empty string "", the provided path for StreamWriter was just representing a **directory** instead of a **file** and an exception was raised.

Now, you should check wether you have a valid path before building a new instance of StreamWriter to get sure you are actually pointing to a File ?

```
Dim writeFile1 As StreamWriter
Dim MyEntirePath As String = "C:\Users\...\Accounts\" + frmLogin.txtUser.Text
MessageBox.Show(MyEntirePath) ' would be enough to be sure your path is correct

' Some test code here...
If everythingOK then ' create the StreamWriter...
    writeFile1 = New StreamWriter(MyEntirePath)
    ' ...
' ...
```

Also, it's not a good idea to create your streamwriter, and use it in another part/method of your code. You never known if one day, you'll change your code, and forget to make the link between

```
Dim writeFile1 As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite("C:\Users\Nick\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\LoginFixed\Accounts\" + frmLogin.txtUser.Text))

' plus
Private Sub btnHunter_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    ...
End Sub

' plus
Public Sub classSelection()
    ...
    writeFile1.Close()
End Sub
```

^^ too much "*here and there*"...

You'll obviously also get an exception if you try to click btnHunter twice.. I don't know what is the purpose of your code nor how it works, it looks like a game.. But I would use File.Exist(..) checks, create the file before, if none, and put that in a Try/Catch to check if I eventually don't have administrator rights to write to that directory. Otherwise, make a code that allow user to read/write files to a custom folder. Andalso, you have :

```
Application.StartupPath
```

^^ Very usefull, like :

```
Dim MyFilePath As String = Application.StartupPath + "\Datas\MyText.txt"
```

After two weeks of coding, I usually forget where I put those "C:\blabla.." or "D:\gnagna\" or what classes actually uses those **absolute** reference paths. I've dropped this way of getting directories long ago since the day I moved to Win7 on another computer and all such applications I developped using that approach was doomed...